# Using NavigationView from Android Design Support Library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, drawerlayout, navigationview

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) to use the new DrawerLayout from the Design Support Library.

It seems that the Android studio isn't recognizing the NavigationView Layout.

This is my main_activity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:padding="20dp">
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Hello"/>
   </LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And when I'm trying to run the project, I'm getting the next error:

> Error: (19) No resource identifier found for attribute 'headerLayout'

But I do have this drawer_header xml file

Comment: can you please add activity and headerLayout code?

Answer (score 17):

My bad!

You should, of course, import the android support design lib to your project.

So the 'dependencies' area in the gradle (app) should look like that:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```