# No resource identifier found for attribute 'headerLayout' in package

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm following an article at: http://androidgifts.com/navigation-view-using-design-support-library/#comment-11

But I'm getting the message:
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'headerLayout' in package 'com.thalasoft.permapp'

Here is my referenced drawer_header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

And my referenced drawer_menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single" >
```

Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BaseActivity"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@+layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@+layout/drawer_menu"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

After reading some threads here I'm still wondering what it is that makes Eclipse not happy.

As a side note, I'd be glad to find a resource on layouts' referencing 101.

Cheers,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824919/using-navigationview-from-android-design-support-library

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong resource identifiers. Delete **`+`** from `@layout`s.

You should specify as

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
app:menu="@layout/drawer_menu"
```

instead of

```
app:headerLayout="@+layout/drawer_header"
app:menu="@+layout/drawer_menu"
```

Comment: I edited the code to reflect your suggestion, and did a project clean up, but it still does give me the exact same error message.

Answer (score 0):

import  support design library in your gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Import material design design library with androidx

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3'
```

and without androidx

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:'
```